How to switch the channel for remote control for prodigit dc electronic？
I want to remote control the prodigit dc electronic which include the 3305F (platform) and two channel 3315F.
download the SCPI commands,  the channel commands not work in 3315F. I can get result of the command "CHAN?" that is "1", but can not set the channel by command "CHAN 1" or "CHAN2" ..etc
The question is how to switch the channel, what's command ?
